# Django - How to implement field that can be ForeignKey or simple text

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on web application using `django`, `django rest-framework` and `angularjs` for the frontend.
I have a django model with field called `destination`, this field need to save one of the following:

- an instance of another class called `Customer`
- plain text

In the app I have a combobox and the user can select a customer or insert plain text...

How can I implement this model field with django?

Thanks!

Comment: just add another field `customer_text` to hold customer data not related with foreign key. your `customer` will be null if you use `customer_text`

Comment: Thats whats I thought to do... Thanks